# In pygame, how do I make an image the background

Tags: python, pygame

This is my code so far but I'm wondering if I can just set an image as a background. I've just started using pygame and I don't know much about it

```
import pygame


pygame.init()


display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A bit Racey')

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
crashed = False
carImg = pygame.image.load('space.gif')
def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x,y))

x =  (display_width * 0.001)
y = (display_height * 0.01)
```

Answer (score 1):

Load a back ground image (e.g. 'background.jpg'), scale it to the size of the screen with [`pygame.transform.smoothscale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale) and `blit` it on the display surface:

```py
background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg').convert()
background = pygame.transform.smoothscale(background, gameDisplay.get_size())
```

```py
gameDisplay.blit(background, (0, 0))
```

Furthermore you have to implement and application loop and the scene has toi be redrawn in every frame. The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).

  > For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A bit Racey')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg').convert()
background = pygame.transform.smoothscale(background, gameDisplay.get_size())

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

crashed = False
carImg = pygame.image.load('space.gif')
def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x,y))

x = round(display_width * 0.001)
y = round(display_height * 0.01)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    # handle the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # update the game states and positions of objects 
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    x += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * 5
    y += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * 5
    x = x % gameDisplay.get_width()
    y = y % gameDisplay.get_height()
     
    # draw the background
    gameDisplay.blit(background, (0, 0))

    # draw the entire scene
    car(x, y)

    # update the display 
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using Python Image Library aka PIL:

```python
from PIL import Image
import pygame
#link to cat image:https://icatcare.org/app/uploads/2018/07/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png
w,h = 500,500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))

#open the image
img = Image.open("cute-cat.png")
#resize the image
img = img.resize((w,h))
#convert to a pygame surface
img = pygame.image.frombuffer(img.tobytes(),(w,h),"RGB")

#blit to screen
win.blit(img,(0,0))
#update the screen
pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: What's wrong with [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html)? the contributor is searching for [tag:pygame] solution.

Comment: This was the solution I knew about. Your solution is way better in any way :)

Comment: when i try, it says 'Image is not defined'.

Comment: Make sure you have the python image library installed. If you don't either use Rabbid76's solution or install is using ```pip install Pilow```